# How to force scientific notation on the vertical axis?

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I have a set of outputs from a function. How may I plot them so that the domain starts from a certain value and at every certain step a value is shown. For example:

```
>> Ox = [40:10:90];
```

the horizontal axis should display all numbers between 40 and 90 that are a multiple of 10.
The vertical axis should be represented similarly. However, it is comprised of a much larger set of values:

```
>> Oy = [1000:500:200000];
```

How can I plot a set of function outputs so that the vertical axis is represented in scientific format(2.6e+3 or 2.6*10^3).

```
               ^
  2.6 * 10 ^3  |
               |
               |
               |                          *
               |                      *     
               |            *    *
               |   *     *
               |
               +-------------------------------->
                40    50    60    70    80   90
```

I can plot the function as:

```
plot(x,fx,'-r');
```

and add labels to each axis:

```
xlabel('domain')
ylabel('codomain')
```

I can't find a way to represent the vertical axis values as scientific values.

Answer (score 1):

For large values Matlab should display them automatically in scientific notation.

Otherwise you can use sprintf like this:

```
x = 1000:200:10000;

plot(x,x.^2)

XSci = 0:0.1e4:0.1e5;
YSci = 0:0.1e4:0.1e5;

set(gca,'XTickLabel',sprintf('%2.0e|',XSci));
set(gca,'YTickLabel',sprintf('%2.0e|',YSci));
```

which outputs this:

[image]

Ok this might not be the best example but you see the point :)

Comment: @Sebi Hi Sebi so is this what you were looking for?